# How to Convert Excel Cell Values Into Individual PNG Files?

Tags: excel, vba, png

Someone just asked this question but it was closed for lack of effort. I spent enough time researching and building this that I felt an answer should be posted (see below). There is no direct answer to this question related to PNG files by cell.

Example of layout

[image]

Desired Output Of Each Word.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This will:

1. create a chart
2. add an image to the chart
3. Loop through each cells in the specified range that is alos in the used range
4. FOr cells that are not empty it will update the image in the chart.
5. Saves chart as a PNG file.

I got some help from [SpreadSheetGuru](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-save-as-picture-file-excel) as well as the legendary [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) on this.

You'll need to update the `Const` to make your ranges.

```
Sub buildPNG()
    Const thePath As String = "C:\Users\SRide\OneDrive\Documents\Junk\" 'or wherever
    Const zWidth As Long = 600
    Const zLength As Long = 400
    Const theFontSize As Long = 96
    Const theRange As String = "A:A"
    
Dim WS As Worksheet, aCell As Range
    Set WS = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    

Dim myChart As ChartObject
        Set myChart = WS.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=50, Width:=zWidth, Top:=50, Height:=zLength)
        
Dim myShape As Shape
    myChart.Activate
    Set myShape = ActiveChart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 1, 1, zWidth, zLength)
    
    With myChart.ShapeRange
      .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
      .Line.Visible = msoFalse
    End With

    With myShape.TextFrame
       
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        .Characters.Font.Size = theFontSize

        For Each aCell In Intersect(WS.UsedRange, WS.Range(theRange)).Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(aCell) Then
                .Characters.Text = aCell.Value2
                myChart.Chart.Export (thePath & aCell.Row & ".PNG")
            End If
        Next aCell
    End With
  
End Sub
```

Comment: If there are 1000 cells then you could create a single chart, put a textbox *inside* the chart, and just change the text of the textbox before each export...

Comment: @TimWilliams Updated. thanks for pointing out what should have been more obvious.